# TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined I'm writing a welcome code but I keep getting that error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const db = require('quick.db')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = (client) => {
  
  
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member, message) => {
     
        let welcomechannel = db.get(`welcome_${message.guild.id}`)
        let welcomemsg = db.get(`Welcomemsg_${message.guild.id}`)
  
       if(welcomechannel = null || undefined) return
   
        if(welcomemsg = null || undefined) welcomemsg = `Hey <@${member.id}>! Make sure to read the rules and have a great time!`

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('GOLD')
        .setDescription(welcomemsg)


        welcomechannel.send(embed)
 

    })
  }
```

Comment: Heads up, your `if` statements aren't going to work. A single `=` if used to assign a variable a value, you need 2 or 3 `=` in an `if` statement. You also need to pass the variable in both conditions:
`if(welcomechannel === null || welcomechannel === undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

The [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event is emitted only with a [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember) parameter.
You have to access the `guild` property from the `member` object.

```
let welcomechannel = db.get(`welcome_${member.guild.id}`)
let welcomemsg = db.get(`Welcomemsg_${member.guild.id}`)
```

There are a couple more issues in your code. `=` is the assignment operator in JS. You want to use `==` or `===` (strict equality) for comparisons. And your condition to check for multiple values isn't right.

```js
if (!welcomechannel === null || welcomechannel === undefined) {
  return
}
```

Or better

```js
if(!welcomechannel) {
  return
}
```

Similarly, you can fix the `welcomemsg` condition with the following.

```js
if(!welcomemsg) {
  welcomemsg = `Hey <@${member.id}>! Make sure to read the rules and have a great time!`
}
```

Or better

```js
const DEFAULT_MESSAGE = `Hey <@${member.id}>! Make sure to read the rules and have a great time!`
const welcomemsg = db.get(`Welcomemsg_${guildId}`) || DEFAULT_MESSAGE
```

Here's the fixed code.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  const { id: guildId } = member.guild
  const welcomechannel = db.get(`welcome_${guildId}`)
  const DEFAULT_MESSAGE = `Hey <@${member.id}>! Make sure to read the rules and have a great time!`
  const welcomemsg = db.get(`Welcomemsg_${guildId}`) || DEFAULT_MESSAGE

  if (!welcomechannel) {
    return
  }

  // rest of the code
})
```

Comment: I did that but I get another error
welcomechannel.send(embed)
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes I replaced message.guild.id with member.guild.id for both welcomemsg and channel

Comment: Your conditions to handle if `welcomechannel` and `welcomemsg` are falsy aren't right. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @Nelly-o Just added an explanation on what's wrong with the conditions.

Comment: Where did  you add it?

Comment: In my answer above :)

Comment: So I tried out the code but I got  a message is not defined error.
So I passed in message as a parameter so 
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member, message) 
but then I got another error


const { id: guildId } = message.guild
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined

Comment: @Nelly-o It should be `member`. Check my updated code above. As I mentioned in my answer, the `guildMemberAdd` event is only called with a single argument - `member`.

Comment: It looks like Discord.js wants to be difficult today...

        welcomechannel.send(embed)
                       ^

TypeError: welcomechannel.send is not a function

Comment: @Nelly-o Ah. Looks like you're calling the `send` method on a `String`. Are you storing the welcome channel 's id or the name in the DB?

Comment: I'm using message.mentions.channels.first()

Comment: But you don't have access to the message in the event handler. You have to get the channel from `member.guild.channels`. Without your answer to my previous question and the discordjs version you're using, it's hard to help.

Comment: I'm on V12 and I'm storing the ID

Comment: So I tried
 const welcomechannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === db.get(`welcome_${guildId}`));

And I don't get any more errors but it doesn't work

Comment: Cool, you got it! In v12, you have to use `member.guild.channels.cache`. In v11,  it is just  `member.guild.channels`

Comment: Thanks! The problem is though that it doesn't sent the message, I also tried to console log hi at the end of the code above welcomechannel.send but it didn't log anything

Comment: You could add ```console.log(db.get(`welcome_${guildId}`))``` and check if it has what you expect.

Comment: I logged it and it logged a channel object so it should send

Comment: I found the error! I logged welcomechannel and it logged undefined!

Comment: Once you add the channel id to the database, you should be good to go.